# Comparing Unit Quaternions ignore YAW

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, quaternions

I am working on a personal project in which I want to compare two unit quaternions. I want to calculate the difference in angle between the two.

This comparing works, but now I came across the situation that I want to ignore the yaw difference between the two. I really can't think of an way to do this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are saying. If you have two quaternions $q_1$ and $q_2$, do you view $q_1$ as a rotation by an angle of $\theta_1$ around an axis $a_1$ and $q_2$ as a rotation by an angle of $\theta_2$ around an axis $a_2$ in 3D-space? In this case: is the difference in angle just $\theta_1 - \theta_2$ or does the angle between $a_1$ and $a_2$ also play a role in this comparison? Also what do you mean by yaw difference?

Comment: I mean, that I have 2 quaternions. Lets say A is a regference point, and B is the current quaternion. I want to know the angle between those 2 from the origin, but ignore the rotation around the Z-axis(yaw). Because in my current solution, I get a 90 degree angle when I rotate 90 degrees over the Z-axis. And this is what I try to ignore. 

I hope this is more clear?

Comment: Quaternions live in a 4-dimensional space, but they define a rotation in 3 dimensional space. So do you want the angle between two vectors in 4-space (ignoring that they have the extra structure of quaternion)? Or do you see $A$ as a point in 3-space and B as a quaternion that defines a rotation of 3-space, sending $A$ to a new point $A'$ in 3-space? In the latter case I read your question as how to compute the angle between the projection of $A$ on the xy-plane and the projection of the new vector $A'$ on the $xy$-plane. Is that correct?

Comment: I see a quaternion as a 4d vector, that can be represented as a 3d vector, in which the w is the rotation over the 3d vector.  I want to calculate the angle between those 2 vectors, ignoring the Z-axis. I primarily use quaternions to overcome gimbal lock.

Comment: Ok, I'm slowly getting there. What do you mean by $w$? Perhaps let's do a concrete example. Let the quaternion $q$ be $1/sqrt(2) (1 + i) = 1/\sqrt{2} + 1/\sqrt{2} i + 0j + 0k = (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}, 0, 0)$. So as a rotation of 3-space it rotates around the $x$-axis over an angle of 90 degrees, right? How would you write it as a 3d vector?

Comment: I have totally automated the thing, and I just convert the quaternions(saved as q = w,x,y,z) and process them. I use 'angle = 2 acos( (dotproduct quat AB) / (lenght quat A * length quat B))' to get the radians of the angle between the 2, I am just not sure how to ignore the Z-axis. I am currently doing the approach found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782658/extracting-yaw-from-a-quaternion). I just zero the Z-axis and let the others be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the concept in the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782658/extracting-yaw-from-a-quaternion). This is that answer:

The quaternion representation of rotation is a variation on axis and angle. So if you rotate by r radians around axis x, y, z, then your quaternion q is:

```
q[0] = cos(r/2)
q[1] = sin(r/2)*x
q[2] = sin(r/2)*y
q[3] = sin(r/2)*z;
```

If you want to create a quaternion that only rotates around the y axis, you zero out the x and z axes and then re-normalize the quaternion:

```
q[1] = 0;
q[3] = 0;
double mag = sqrt(q[0]*q[0] + q[2]*q[2]);
q[0] /= mag;
q[2] /= mag;
```

If you want the resulting angle:

```
double ang = 2*acos(q[0]);
```

This assumes that the quaternion representation is stored: w,x,y,z. If both q[0] and q[2] are zero, or close to it, the resulting quaternion should just be {1,0,0,0}.